# Excel VBA | Union method on another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, select, union, worksheet

I am trying to get a specific Worksheet exported to PDF. The script is called from another Worksheet. As there can be a case where I don't want to print/convert all sites into the PDF, I have some IF-methodes included. "If the site x is unwanted, do not include it on the UNION-method and therefore do not convert it to PDF". Works fine, as long as I call the script within the destination Worksheet.

How can I call the script from another Worksheet? I always get the error, that the Range-Object can not be selected (in line: Union(intSeite1, intSeite2, intSeite3, intSeite4, intSeite5, intSeite6).Select).

cheers and thanks,
Martin

```
Sub export()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim rngSeite1 As Range
Dim rngSeite2 As Range
Dim rngSeite3 As Range
Dim rngSeite4 As Range
Dim rngSeite5 As Range
Dim rngSeite6 As Range
Dim rngDruckbereich As Range

With Worksheets("Ausgabe")
    .Unprotect

    Set intSeite1 = .Range("A1:A92").EntireRow

    If .Range("a94") <> 1 Then
        Set intSeite2 = .Range("A94:A205").EntireRow
    Else
        Set intSeite2 = Nothing
    End If

    If .Range("a207") <> 1 Then
        Set intSeite3 = .Range("A207:A403").EntireRow
    Else
        Set intSeite3 = Nothing
    End If

    If .Range("a405") <> 1 Then
        Set intSeite4 = .Range("A405:A516").EntireRow
    Else
        Set intSeite4 = Nothing
    End If

    If .Range("a518") <> 1 Then
        Set intSeite5 = .Range("A518:A629").EntireRow
    Else
        Set intSeite5 = Nothing
    End If

    If .Range("a631") <> 1 Then
        Set intSeite6 = .Range("A631:A716").EntireRow
    Else
        Set intSeite6 = Nothing
    End If
End With

    If Not intSeite4 Is Nothing And Not intSeite5 Is Nothing Then
        Union(intSeite1, intSeite2, intSeite3, intSeite4, intSeite5, intSeite6).Select
    ElseIf Not intSeite4 Is Nothing Then
        Union(intSeite1, intSeite2, intSeite3, intSeite4, intSeite6).Select
    ElseIf Not intSeite5 Is Nothing Then
        Union(intSeite1, intSeite2, intSeite3, intSeite5, intSeite6).Select
    Else
        Union(intSeite1, intSeite2, intSeite3, intSeite5, intSeite6).Select
    End If

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Worksheets("Eingabe").Range("D41"), _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

With Worksheets("Ausgabe")
    .Protect
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to activate the sheet before you can select anything on it but you shouldn't have to select anything-use a range variable

```
   Dim rngSeite1              As Range
   Dim rngArea                As Range

   With Worksheets("Ausgabe")
      .Unprotect

      Set rngSeite1 = .Range("A1:A92").EntireRow
      For Each rngArea In .Range("A94:A205,A207:A403,A405:A516,A518:A629,A631:A716").Areas
         If rngArea.Cells(1).Value <> 1 Then
            Set rngSeite1 = Union(rngSeite1, rngArea.EntireRow)
         End If
      Next rngArea
      rngSeite1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Worksheets("Eingabe").Range("D41"), _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

      .Protect
   End With
```